# They say, from aperire

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle consists of 10 letters and is of the form ____ ____

---

[image]

---

**From smallest to largest, row by row**

[image]

**Row 1: K.A b. Row 2: W.M b. Row 3: H.S b. Row 4: N.M.B b. Row 5: G.M b.**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the form'. With my browser I can ses just two quite long lines, which suggests two words. I needed to drag a mouse pointer over that and select them character-by-character to discover each line consists of 4 underscore characters. Does that mean anything? Say, the words are 4-letter each? But how the solution is 10-letters, then? Or are they equal length...? Or just there are two words and that's all?

Comment: It's just two giant letters ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing we need to do here is rearrange the 30 tiles in a meaningful way. We can do this by noticing:

> That each run of letters is prefixed by one of 'F', 'S', 'T', 'FO' or 'FI', and suffixed by one of 'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F', 'S' or 'SU'. This is a combination of the first letters of an ordinal number (**F**irst, **S**econd, **T**hird, **FO**urth, **FI**fth) and the first letters of a day of the week (**M**onday, **T**uesday, **W**ednesday, **TH**ursday, **F**riday, **S**aturday, **SU**nday).
>
>  Noticing next that there are two more occurrences of the 'TH' and 'F' suffixes than the others, we can arrange the tiles in **calendar order**, beginning with 'FTH' (First Thursday) and continuing day-by-day and week-by-week until we reach the following arrangement:
>
>  [image]

What do we have here? Look next at the numbers in the first four columns. These look a lot like:

> **years**. In fact, coupled with the information below the puzzle image, these are **birth years** of famous people with the listed initials, which is hinted at by the 'b.' element ('b.' for 'born'). Moreover, we can find famous people with these initials who don't just fit these birth years but also specifically have birthdays *in April* on the days that correspond to the numbers in the fifth and sixth columns:
>
>  Row 1: K.A b. 1938-Apr-08 = **[Kofi Annan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kofi_Annan)**;
>  Row 2: W.M b. 1940-Apr-01 = **[Wangari Maathai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wangari_Maathai)**;
>  Row 3: H.S b. 1949-Apr-06 = **[Horst Störmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Ludwig_St%C3%B6rmer)**;
>  Row 4: N.M.B b. 1862-Apr-02 = **[Nicholas Murray Butler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Murray_Butler)**;
>  Row 5: G.M b. 1874-Apr-25 = **[Guglielmo Marconi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guglielmo_Marconi)**.

What might our desired 2-word 10-letter answer be? Well, what do all these people have in common?

> All of them are recipients of a **NOBEL PRIZE**! (Peace 2001, Peace 2004, Physics 1998, Peace 1931 and Physics 1909, respectively)

Comment: Everything looks good and you got the right answer ofc. Nice job! :)

Comment: Slight typo - think you mean suffixes instead of prefixes in the second spoilered paragraph?

Comment: @Mohirl Ah yes, I can spot a formatting fail as well - will fix them both. Thanks for the ping :)

Comment: As for the title, rot13(gur jbeq "Ncevy" vf vaqrrq qrevirq sebz Yngva "ncrever").